# std::for_each() for a map gives invalid initialization error

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I'm relatively new to STL and particularly algorithm library.
I'm trying to iterate over a `std::multimap`, where both key and value are of type `std::string`, using `std::for_each()` function and perform some task.

Here's my `std::multimap`:

```
std::multimap<std::string, std::string> myMap;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    myMap.insert(std::make_pair("key", "value"));
}
```

And here is the line with `for_each()` function:

```
std::for_each(myMap.begin(), myMap.end(), ask);
```

The `ask()` function is defined as following:

```
void ask(std::pair<std::string, std::string>& entry) {
    // do something...
}
```

The program gives me the following error:

> error: invalid initialization of reference of type
>   'std::__cxx11::basic_string&' from expression of type
>   'std::pair,
>   std::__cxx11::basic_string >'

I know that, the problem is on the line with `for_each()` function and I assume it's because the parameter of `ask()` function is not correct. 
But to my knowledge, each entry of the `std::multimap` is represented as a `std::pair`, so shouldn't the `ask()` function take a `std::pair` object as its parameter?

Comment: @JeJo The ask() method is pretty long, so I decided to keep the code cleaner by writing a separate function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default allocator used for `std::multimap` is

```
std::allocator<std::pair<const Key, T>
```

So the keys in `std::multimap` are `const` which makes the type as

```
std::pair<const std::string, std::string>
```

where as `ask()` expects parameter as a reference to type

```
std::pair<std::string, std::string>
```

Change `ask()` as

```
void ask(std::pair<const std::string, std::string>& entry)
{
}
```

Comment: I've tried it out, but it didn't work. It gives the exact same error

Comment: @HidayetRzayev [works here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/s0tGorsdmRZIWvsM)

Comment: EDIT: sorry, I forgot to add const in my function declaration as well, it works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

The element type of `std::multimap<std::string, std::string>` is `std::pair<const std::string, std::string>`. Note the `const`

Answer (score 1):

Rather than guessing at the element type of the map, you can ask it directly.

```
void ask(std::multimap<std::string, std::string>::reference entry) {
    // do something...
}
```

It might be a good idea to make a type alias for this map type, so that you don't have to repeat it

```
using myMap_t = std::multimap<std::string, std::string>;

void ask(myMap_t::reference entry) {
    // do something...
}

int main() {
    myMap_t myMap;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        myMap.insert(myMap_t::value_type("key", "value"));
    }

    std::for_each(myMap.begin(), myMap.end(), ask);
}
```